# How do I set up a customized training plan in DailyBurn?

Tags: customization

I've been using [DailyBurn](http://dailyburn.com) for a while now to keep track of my weight loss (or, more accurately, my lack thereof). DailyBurn has a lot of cool features I don't use, but I would like to try out their customized training plans.

How can I set one up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you go to

http://dailyburn.com/training_plans

and select, what you want. after you signed up for a plan, the you select, when / how often you  want to work out. thats it. they fill in the plan (you could create such a plan as well) for you, tell you when to workout, what to do, how to do it.

just sign up for a plan and do it :)